# Как редактировать embed message? [Discord.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Как можно отредактировать embed в ранее отправленном сообщении с embed? При bot.rest.methods.updateMessage вместо embed возвращает его тип (Object [object]).

Необходимо для мониторинга.

Comment: выложите примеры.

Comment: Точно не знаю как обновлять embed message. Но знаю, что нужно допустим каждую минуту удалять прошлое сообщение и высылать новое.

Answer (score 1):

Сообщение редактируется таким способом:

```js
message.channel.send(embed).then(message => message.edit(new_embed))
```

Если же вы хотите добавить какой-либо элемент в уже существующий `embed`:

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

embed.addField("Поле", "Подполе")
```

Answer (score 0):

Редактировать embed можно при помощи `message.edit(embed);`
Зависит от версии discord.js На 11 как сверху!